# CSS: How to crop image that has any size?

Tags: html, css, image, crop

I have a website where users can upload their photos and I'd like to prepare a page, where I would display all uploaded images nicely sorted.
The problem is, that someone upload the picture in **400x400px** resolution, someone in **1400x800px** and someone in **300x500px**.

On the page, where I would like to print out all the uploaded images, I would like to print each image in the size **100x200px**. I tried to manually set up the dimensions of the images, like:

```
<img src="img.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 200px" />
```

But the page looks terrible, all images are blurred. What is the best approach to do that?
Maybe to crop the area of **100x200px** from each image display it? But how to do that?

Comment: well, you can use wideimage plugin of php!

Comment: the best way is to generate thumbnails server side. That way you avoid loading too large images when you only need to print them in 100*200.

Comment: Another suggestion is to use a plugin like http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/images.html although you'll probably still have to set the width to something and let the height scale.

Comment: As @BiAiB suggests you, you really should resize huge images server-side. If images are only 2-3 times larger than thumbnails it is tolerable, but scaling 1400x800px image down to 100x200px seems way too wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would try this :

- specify width of 100px on each image
- surround your image by a div with 100x200px size and overflow: hidden

Comment: And center image horizontally within this container `div`. This way you will preserve correct aspect ratio of down-scaled images.